# Getting value between '-' in google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im trying to get the number between '-' and '-' in google sheets but after trying many things I still havent been able to find the solution.

```
Data record 1
England Premier League
West Ham vs Crystal Palace
2.090 - 3.47 - 3.770
```

Expected value = `3.47`

```
Data record 2
England League Two
Carlisle vs Scunthorpe
2.830 - 3.15 - 2.820
```

Expected value = `3.15`

Hopefully someone can help me out

Comment: there are many websites that allow you to just scrape the live odds for all football matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either of the following

option 1.

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(AE1:AE4," \d+\.\d+ ")*1))
```

option 2.

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(AE1:AE4,".* - (\d+\.\d+) ")))
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "- (\d+(?:.\d+)?) -")*1))
```

[image]